# in sts embeded apache tomcat server can not start

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, spring-boot, jsp

I'm quite new to spring and spring boot application. Getting the error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource. It says unable to build EntityManagerFactory. Error displayed in console:

1. when i tried to run embeded apache tomcat i got this erroe
2. please tell me what is problem

```html
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.4.RELEASE)

Apr 23, 2019 1:44:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
Apr 23, 2019 1:44:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.17]
Apr 23, 2019 1:44:20 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Apr 23, 2019 1:44:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
Apr 23, 2019 1:44:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Tomcat]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/metadata/ClassMetadata
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
 at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
 at com.amol.location.LocationwebApplication.main(LocationwebApplication.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/metadata/ClassMetadata
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 at org.hibernate.persister.internal.StandardPersisterClassResolver.singleTableEntityPersister(StandardPersisterClassResolver.java:59)
 at org.hibernate.persister.internal.StandardPersisterClassResolver.getEntityPersisterClass(StandardPersisterClassResolver.java:39)
 at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:74)
 at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:154)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:295)
 at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
 at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939)
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
 ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.metadata.ClassMetadata
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:370)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 ... 54 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:717)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:419)
 at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
 at sun.misc.Resource.getBytes(Resource.java:124)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:462)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
 ... 60 more
```

**The pom.xml file

---

**

### pom.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>
 <groupId>com.amol.location</groupId>
 <artifactId>locationweb</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>locationweb</name>
 <description>Location Module</description>

 <properties>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>


  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

 </dependencies>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

</project>
```

### application.properties

```html
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/projectdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsps/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, invalid LOC header means your local maven repository got corrupted.
Go to `~/.m2/repository` directory, find the hibernate directory, **delete it**, and rebuild the project.

Comment: Same problem and solution . However i deleted a different directory HOME_DIR\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed